# App terminates on run

Tags: swift, parse-platform, xcode6

I am making an app in Swift and Xcode 6 and everything has been working fine, until now. When I go to run it, I get a delegate error and it crashes immediately. Here is the debugger code:

```
2014-11-11 10:18:48.282 Pro Cast[2987:65789] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
      'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'You have to call setApplicationId:clientKey: on Parse to configure Parse.'
```

I've never had an issue with Parse up tot his point. What can I do?

Comment: Are you using any Parse component before calling [Parse setApplicationId:clientKey:]?

Comment: No, I always set it before I call anything for it. But the delegate error leads me to believe that I need to set it in the app delegate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set your Parse applicationID and clientID in the AppDelegate.m. Specifically in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` You can get your appID and clientID on the parse website.

Don't forget to import the parse framework.